# react fetch POST dont work

Tags: react-native

I have a react component that contains a form, the content of which I send a fetch  POST request to the server

I also tried axios, but nothing happened

But when I submit form, I get 204 no content in network ,I do not understand what I missed, if I need to attach a response from the server

here is my code,tnx

```
class NewRecord extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        address: ''
    };

    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePhoneChange = this.handlePhoneChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAddressChange = this.handleAddressChange.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = [
        {
            data:
                {
                    name: this.state.name,
                    phone: this.state.phone,
                    address: this.state.address
                }
        }
    ];
    console.log(data);
        fetch('http://server.noorsoft.ru:9022/api/records/:id', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-type': 'application/json, charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
}

handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
}

handlePhoneChange(event) {
    this.setState({phone: event.target.value});
}

handleAddressChange(event) {
    this.setState({address: event.target.value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <form className='form__row' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleNameChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="PHONE"
                value={this.state.phone}
                onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="ADDRESS"
                value={this.state.address}
                onChange={this.handleAddressChange}
            />
            <button type='submit'>save</button>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 204 means the server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content. Based on the fetch url you're using post on a get url. When i paste that link `http://server.noorsoft.ru:9022/api/records/5ada5b61708c9c5acbddf636` i get a specific set of record. I think you're using wrong post url